# pandas df.apply returns series of the same list (like map) where should return one list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes a row of the daraframe (pd.Series) and returns one list. The idea is to apply it to dataframe and generate a new pd.Series of lists, one per each row:

```
sale_candidats = closings.apply(get_candidates_3, axis=1,
                                sales=sales_ts,
                                settings=settings,
                                reduce=True)
```

However, it seems that pandas try to map the list it returns (for the first row, probably) to original row, and raises an error (even despite reduce=True):

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 8), indices imply (10, 23)
```

When I convert function to return set instead of the list, the whole thing starts working - except returning a data frame with the same shape and index/columns name as an original data frame, except that every cell is filled with corresponding row's set().

Looks a lot like a bug to me... how can I return one `pd.Series` instead?

Comment: add `axis=1` to your `apply()` call

Comment: it was there all the time, take a look at the code

Comment: I missed that. Can you post the arguments for `get_candidates_3()`?

Comment: def get_candidates_3(closing, sales, settings: dict=_default_) -> list:

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this behaviour is, indeed, a bug in the latest version of pandas. take a look at the issue:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/18577

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the function in a for loop, because that's all that apply does. You wouldn't notice a large speed penalty.

Comment: yeah, I can loop over, but still would like to use actual `apply` and `progress_apply`

Comment: get_candidates_3(sale_candidats .iloc[0,:], settings... etc. )